# React Native Navigation doesnt work with Expo

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

Trying to build android app with Expo.
It builds, but it crashes immediately after launch.

I have cut down my application as much as possible to understand what the problem is. And I realized that Expo doesn't want to work with React Native Navigation. Even the example from this page immediately crashes (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation/).
Please tell me what could be the problem.

Comment: Can you please share your package.json? Also please make sure to run expo install rather than npm install to install expo compatible packages

Answer (score 0):

[React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation) works with Expo. Follow documentation, and install the required dependencies. You might've missed something.
The dependencies needed to implement stack navigation in the Expo project are listed below.

```
npm install @react-navigation/native
npx expo install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
npm install @react-navigation/native-stack
```